# grunt-war: dynamically define options

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Basically what I have is a project set up to serve to different combinations of environments and targets by running, for example, `grunt serve:local:1st` or `grunt serve:test:2nd`; now that I need to actually build for those differents environments/targets I'm using grunt-war.

Thing is, I need different war options depending on my target (for example, different `war_name` and `webxml_display_name`). From what I'm seeing, grunt-war doesn't seem to take arguments... I know I could pass options like `--war_name=*name*` and pick them up with `grunt.option('war_name')`, but since I'm already passing the target in the build task's parameters, isn't there some way to use that to define grunt-war's options internally? It would also avoid having to pass many arguments which will be always the same as long as I'm building for the same target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I should say I found the way to do it or a way around it, but here's what I ended up doing and it worked:

Defined a var before `grunt.initConfig` with the options I want to dynamically define and some default values:

```
var globalConfig = {
  war_name:'name',
  webxml_display_name:'display_name'
};
```

Defined it within `grunt.initConfig` to make it available to tasks:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  globalConfig: globalConfig,
  ...
```

Parameterized the `grunt-war` configuration:

```
war: {
  target: {
    options: {
      war_dist_folder: './dist',
      war_verbose: true,
      war_name: '<%= globalConfig.war_name %>',
      webxml_welcome: 'index.html',
      webxml_display_name: '<%= globalConfig.webxml_display_name %>'
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Defined a task to set the parameters:

```
grunt.registerTask('war-config', function(target){
  if(target==='1st'){
    globalConfig.war_name='name_1st';
    globalConfig.webxml_display_name='display_name_1st';
  }else if(target==='2nd'){
    ...
  }else ...
});
```

And finally called the task within the `build` task, before `grunt-war` is called:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function(environment, target) {
  grunt.task.run([
    'clean:dist',
    ...
    'war-config:'+target,
    'war'
  ]);
});
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it seems to work as intended.